# Form errors - required field

Tags: python, html, django

I am building a CRUD app on Django.

I can create, read, and delete just fine, but the update function does not work. I have edited the `views.py` file (it was a template) to print the error.

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
#models.py

from django.db import models  

class Item(models.Model):  
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    etitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eauthor = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    estatus = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Item"
```

```
#views.py

...

def edit(request, id):  
    item = Item.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'item':item})
    
def update(request, id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = ItemForm(request.POST, instance = item) 
    print(form.errors)  
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
        except Exception as e: print(e)
        return redirect("/items/show")
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'item': item})

...
```

I guess the problem has to be in `edit.html` file, but I cannot figure it out.

```
#edit.html

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Index</title>  
    {% load static %}  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/update/{{item.id}}">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
    <div class="container">  
<br>  
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
    <h3>Update Details</h3>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Type:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
        <input type="text" name="etype" id="id_etype" required maxlength="100" value="{{ item.etype }}" />  
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
        <input type="text" name="etitle" id="id_etitle" required maxlength="100" value="{{ item.etitle }}" />  
    </div>  
  </div>  
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
        <input type="text" name="eatuhor" id="id_eauthor" required maxlength="100" value="{{ item.eauthor }}" />  
    </div>  
  </div>  
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Status:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
        <input type="text" name="estatus" id="id_estatus" required maxlength="20" value="{{ item.estatus }}" />  
    </div>  
  </div>   
  </div> 
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
    </div>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S: I am new to both Django and Software Development, so any kind of feedback is welcome.

Comment: You're using a form, but then rendering all the markup yourself. This complicates things massively. I'd recommend starting simple, just display the form django's own way with something like `{{ form.as_p }}` and then try to submit the form like that. Django will then show you what errors are in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use UpdateView, its really easier.
Show here [Click](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Example views.py

```
class ItemUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'edit.html'
```

Example edit.html:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```